# Large table with automatic font resize + cols and rows resize?

Tags: tables, pdftex

I am user really the first steps in the TeX world.

I have a very large table which is 10 x 11 (10 cols x 11 lines). I would like to have a single page and that Latex takes completely care about the cells/rows size + font size, in order to make it fit well.

I am using PDFLATEX on Ubuntu.

Here a my code.

```
    \begin{tabular}{|*{10}{c|}}
\hline 
1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
 \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: you should extend your code snippet to complete but small document. without knowing your page layout solutions can lead to unacceptable table looking (see @JiyuuSensei answer below), which is useless (you cannot store elephant into suitcase). you should consider some other solution for your table (rotate it to landscape orientation).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `resizebox` from the `adjustbox` package, defining the width as long as the textwidth. This puts the table inside this box. I copied your code and added two things: the `\usepackage{adjustbox}` in the preamble, and a `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{` before the `\begin{tabular}`. Note that there is an open bracket, which we will close `}` only after the `\end{tabular}`. This will resize your table to match the width of your text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\noindent
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{c|}}
    \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
    1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 & 1.00000000000000 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shoe page layout, code for them are not included in above mwe)

Comment: i took liberty and add to your solution image of received table.

Comment: Thank you, that does make it more clear. I'll remember to use page layout indicators too for future images concerning geometry, they really add much value.

Comment: i added image for show, how your suggestion is technically correct but for readers  worthless. numbers is not possible read without magnifying glass :-). see my comment below question.